# Как применить класс к разным блокам при клике?

Tags: javascript

Как при клике на кнопку "загрузить файл" у каждой кнопки загружалась свой файл. Сейчас на какую бы кнопку не нажал все применяется к первому. Спасибо

```js
const inputFiles = document.querySelectorAll('.input-file');
if (inputFiles) {
    const inputFileClose = document.querySelector('.input-file-close');
    const inputFileName = document.querySelector('.input-file-name');
    let pattern = /((?:.(?!\(\d+\)))+.)(?:\(\d+\))?\..+/
    inputFiles.forEach(inputFile => {
        inputFile.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
            inputFileName.textContent = this.files[0].name.match(pattern)[1]
            inputFileName.classList.add("_active")
            inputFileClose.classList.add("_active")
        });
        inputFileClose.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
            inputFileName.classList.remove("_active")
            inputFileClose.classList.remove("_active")
        });
    });
}
```

```css
.left-form-calculator__files {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: -10px -5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-inputs {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 175px;
    height: 53px;
    padding: 10px 5px 10px 0;
    margin: 0 0 0 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-input-value {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f8f8fa;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2857142857;
    color: #91919b;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name._active {
    display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close{
   position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer
    min-width: 18px;
    height: 18px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #f5912d;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close:hover::before {
    background: #af671e
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close._active {
    display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__file {
    display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #e1e1eb;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
    transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file:hover {
    border: 1px solid #f5912d
}

.left-form-calculator__label-icon {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0
}

.left-form-calculator__label-text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.2857142857;
    color: #91919b
}
```

```html
<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file" id="input-file">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file" id="input-file">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда копируете и размножаете чужой код, то проверяйте его на наличие одинаковых *name* и *id*.

```js
const inputFiles = document.querySelectorAll('[type="file"]');
if (inputFiles) {
  let pattern = /((?:.(?!\(\d+\)))+.)(?:\(\d+\))?\..+/;

  inputFiles.forEach(inputFile => {
    let parent = inputFile.closest('.left-form-calculator__files');
    let inputFileClose = parent.querySelector('.input-file-close');
    let inputFileName = parent.querySelector('.input-file-name');
    inputFile.addEventListener('change', function() {
      inputFileName.textContent = this.files[0].name.match(pattern)[1]
      inputFileName.classList.add('_active')
      inputFileClose.classList.add('_active')
    });
    inputFileClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
      inputFileName.classList.remove('_active')
      inputFileClose.classList.remove('_active')
    });
  });
}
```

```css
.left-form-calculator__files {
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0 0 0;
  margin: -10px -5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-inputs {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 175px;
  height: 53px;
  padding: 10px 5px 10px 0;
  margin: 0 0 0 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__file-input-value {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 5px
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f8f8fa;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2857142857;
  color: #91919b;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-name._active {
  display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer min-width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #f5912d;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close:hover::before {
  background: #af671e
}

.left-form-calculator__input-file-close._active {
  display: block
}

.left-form-calculator__file {
  display: none
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid #e1e1eb;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  -o-transition: all .3s ease 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease 0s
}

.left-form-calculator__label-file:hover {
  border: 1px solid #f5912d
}

.left-form-calculator__label-icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0
}

.left-form-calculator__label-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.2857142857;
  color: #91919b
}
```

```html
<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file-1" id="input-file-1">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file-1">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename-1"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="left-form-calculator__files">
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-inputs">
    <input class="left-form-calculator__file input-file" type="file" name="file-2" id="input-file-2">
    <label class="left-form-calculator__label-file" for="input-file-2">
      <div class="left-form-calculator__label-text">Загрузить файл</div>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="left-form-calculator__file-input-value">
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-name input-file-name" type="text" id="filename-2"></div>
    <div class="left-form-calculator__input-file-close input-file-close _icon-close">x</div>
  </div>
</div>
```